# Apache XAMPP get error while start after installing PostgreSql

Tags: apache, postgresql, xampp

I just installed PgSQL on my xampp but I got this error when I start Apache.

```
11:30:35 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:30:35 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:30:35 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:30:35 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:30:35 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:30:35 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:30:35 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

I already install pgsql into `C:/XAMPP/pgsql` and phppgadmin into `C:/XAMPP/phppgadmin` and I also add this code into `httpd-xampp.conf` :

```
    Alias /phppgadmin “C:/xampp/phppgadmin/”
    <Directory “C:/xampp/phppgadmin”>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

But when I start the apache in XAMPP Control Panel I got that error.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong configuration looks like Typo, it should `"` not `“`